# I am trying to execute my code at a certain time every day and its not working

Tags: python, function, bots, schedule

[image]

Am I doing something completely wrong. I've been trying to fix this for so long. it prints once and then keeps running but doesn't print anything else.

```
import schedule
import time

def bot():
    schedule.every(1).day.at("6:41").do(bot)
    print("ya")

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Check the indentation on your print() call?

Comment: `print("ya")` indentation should be inside the `bot()`??

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation [here](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) for a good example of how this should work

Simple answer is your `bot()` is trying to recursively execute itself, but the only thing that happens when it runs itself is that it tells itself to run itself again in one day at 6:41...meanwhile no `print()` statement is executed because it doesn't exist inside the `bot()` function.

Your code executes the `print()` statement once because it runs it immediately after defines `bot()`.

You never call `bot()` in this code, so that function never actually does anything.

Easy solution is to put your desired functionality in your `bot()` function and then add it to the `schedule` like so:

```py
import schedule
import time

def bot():
    print("ya")

schedule.every(1).day.at("6:41").do(bot)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```